# How to test if a cell matches given REGEX in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: regex, libreoffice-calc

I have a cell, and I want to test if it passes a specific pattern: 3-4 alphanumeric, minus, 3-4 alphanumeric, minus, 4 digits, minus, 1 or more digits.

In other words, I want "TEST-TST-1234-33" to pass, but "TST-12345343" or anything else to fail.

Regex would be trivial: `^[A-Z0-9]{3,4}-[A-Z0-9]{3,4}-[:digit:]{4}-[:digit:]+$`. The problem is that I cannot find anything to test if a cell is exactly in that specific format. Something like:

```
= IF(CELL_PASSES_REGEX(A2, "^[A-Z0-9]{3,4}-[A-Z0-9]{3,4}-[:digit:]{4}-[:digit:]+$"), "pass", "fail")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use the MATCH() function directly, or combine MATCH() with one of the [Information Functions](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.6/lo/text/scalc/01/04060104.html?&DbPAR=SHARED). If your regex matches, MATCH() returns 1, otherwise an #N/A error. For a boolean result, embed MATCHES() into ISERROR() or into ISNUMBER(). ISNUMBER() will return true if your regex matches, while ISERROR behaves opposite, so ISNUMBER() may be the best option to reflect if a certain cell matches your regex:

```regexp
=ISNUMBER(MATCH("^[:alnum:]{3,4}-[:alnum:]{3,4}-[:digit:]{4}-[:digit:]+$";A2))
```